# Pass a pointer to a function that receives a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, segmentation-fault

I have a function similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void increaseRef(int& x) {
    x += 3;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Now I have a pointer that should be passed to this function, I can deference it:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int* x;
    *x = 3;
    increaseRef(*x);
    return 0;
}
```

Or not:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int* x;
    *x = 3;
    increaseRef(x);
    return 0;
}
```

In the second case I got an error:

```
main.cpp:15:15: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘int*’
  increaseRef(x);
```

In the first case I got a segfault.

Comment: *Both* cases invoke UB. long before the function call.

Comment: The second one doesn't compile, not the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't  do this:

```
int* x;
*x = 3;
```

because `x` doesn't point to a valid `int`. De-referencing it us *undefined behaviour*.

You could do this:

```
int y = 3;
int* x = &y;
```

Then you can pass `*x` to the function.

```
increaseRef(*x);
```

Comment: I think `int* x = new int();` would make more sense in this context

Comment: @Paranaix I see absolutely no reason for that. Also, I don't want to go into the whole dynamic memory thing, especially without knowing the real use case. The point is to have a pointer point to something, so that it can be de-referenced. Then, to show how to pass it to a function expecting a reference.

Answer (score 3):

After the edit, I see your point better.

In the second case, you are *referencing the reference itself*.
In other terms, you are giving an `&(int*)` to the function instead of an `&(int)`.

Otherwise:

You are not allocating any memory for your pointer.

You need to call malloc() or new() before you can dereference the pointer.

Try

```
int *x=new int;
*x=3;
increaseRef(*x);
delete x; //and don't forget to delete your pointers, or you will leak memory.
return 0;
```

You can also pass the allocation to c++ by defining a local variable, as @juanchopanza stated. That way, memory will be automatically freed on return (and the variable will be created on the stack), the downside being that after your function defining the given variable returns, your pointer will be invalid, and if you dereference it outside the function, you will get a segfault.

Comment: You are conflating two things here: a pointer pointing to a valid object, and dynamic allocation. You don't *need* to call `malloc` or `new`. You only need to do so if you want dynamic allocation.

Comment: By defining an empty pointer, it will point to unallocated area. By my guess, this is a learning exercise, so the point is that memory has to be allocated first, either implicitly, or explicitly. Otherwise, the pointers are totally redundant, since you can simply do `int y=3; increaseRef(y)`.

Comment: It is a learning exercise, so you shouldn't make people think that you need to call `malloc` or `new` every time you want to set a pointer.

Comment: you are quite stubborn, are you?
I repeat: pointers are not in any way mandated in this use case.